# Retrieve Sharepoint online data from an externally hosted website (might be on Azure)

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, development

I need to retrieve SPO document information from SPO into a public website. I would imagine an app with some secret keys would do it. Or have a kind of authentication master account to enable my external app/website to connect to SPO and retrieve the data through normal services ways like CSOM/REST.

I cannot find any example how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use form-based auth or Oauth flow to connect to SPO for data retriveal. Please take a referecne of below example:

- [Connect to SharePoint Online, On premise and Extranet using CSOM](https://www.codesharepoint.com/sharepoint-tutorial/connect-to-sharepoint-online-on-premise-and-extranet-using-csom)
- http://www.ktskumar.com/2016/05/authenticate-sharepoint-using-pnp-authentication-manager/

For more details of pnp csom AuthenticationManager, please refer to:

- https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/AuthenticationManager.cs

BR